# Eigenvector calculation in C++

Tags: c++, eigenvector

How can I make a function in cpp in order to calculate the first "Q" eigenvectors of a matrix M?

I tried using this code, but  failed.

```
#include <RcppArmadillo.h>   

using namespace arma; 

 mat M;
 int Q;

 vec getEigen(M,Q) { 
 return eig_sym(M, Q);      
  }
```

The error message says:

> "no matching function for call to "arma::col(arma::mat&, int&)"

Any idea? I am new at cpp and don't know what the message means.

Thanks

Comment: You mention "failed" and "failing" here, without any indication of what you mean.  Please add sufficient detail to your question so it can be answered.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! i added information about the error.

Comment: Have you checked the [documentation for Armadillo](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#eig_sym)?  It's not clear what purpose an integer called `Q` serves here, but that doesn't appear to match the syntax of anything in the docs.  Also, your function definition is incorrect.  Get rid of the globals and define as something like `vec getEigen(const mat& M, int Q) { ... }`.

Comment: What do you mean by "first"? In which order?

Comment: The first Q eigenvectors are those associated with the first Q eigenvalues, which are ordered in descendent order being 1 the max eigenvalue.

Answer (score 1):

As noted in the comments, there is no function in Armadillo that returns a subset of the eigenvalues. However, one can combine `.head()` or `.tail()` with `eigen_sym()` to extract a subset. In addition, it makes sense to use `reverse()`, since Armadillo returns eigenvalues in ascending order. For convenience I am using [RcppArmadillo](https://cran.r-project.org/package=RcppArmadillo) with [Rcpp attributes](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Rcpp/vignettes/Rcpp-attributes.pdf) here:

```
// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]
#include <RcppArmadillo.h>   

// [[Rcpp::export]]
arma::vec getEigen(const arma::mat& M, int Q) { 
  return arma::reverse(arma::eig_sym(M).tail(Q));      
}

/*** R
set.seed(42)
N <- 10
m <- matrix(rnorm(N * N), N, N)
m <- m + t(m)
getEigen(m, N/2)
 */
```

Output upon calling `Rcpp::sourceCpp` on the file:

```
// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]
#include <RcppArmadillo.h>   

// [[Rcpp::export]]
arma::vec getEigen(const arma::mat& M, int Q) { 
  return arma::reverse(arma::eig_sym(M).tail(Q));      
}

/*** R
set.seed(42)
N <- 10
m <- matrix(rnorm(N * N), N, N)
m <- m + t(m)
getEigen(m, N/2)
 */
```

This is only for the eigenvalues, not the eigenvectors. Extracting the Eigenvectors shouldn't be difficult, though.